# What is a good way to determine a fixed hash function for a hardcoded hash table?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Often I find myself needing a hash table whose values are known at compile time and are known to never change.

I want to know if there is a standard way to generate a tailor made algorithm that is to be used only for a specific hash table so that it does not need to be constructed at runtime, and ensuring that there are no collisions.

The worst algorithm of this kind would be just to do a series of if statements, but this kinda ruins the O(N)ness.

I want to know if there is some existing algorithm for mapping fixed number of unique strings to indexes from 0 to number of unique strings.

For example; I might have a hash table

```
{
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2", 
    "three": "3"
}
```

One naive attempt at creating such a hardcoded table would be to make a function with an internal table of entry pairs and come up with some arbitrary discrimination, such as one below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

static const char *my_hash(const char *input)
{   
    const struct {
        const char *key;
        const char *value;
    } h_table[] = {
        {"three", "3"},
        {"one", "1"},
        {"two", "2"}
    };

    int hash;
    int len = strlen(input);

    if (len != 3 && len != 5) {
        return (char *)0;
    }        

    hash = (int)ceil((((input[1] - 102) / 4) - 1) / 2.0);    

    return h_table[hash].value;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts(my_hash("one"));
    puts(my_hash("two"));
    puts(my_hash("three"));

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a known algorithm for generating algorithms of this sort?

Summary: Is there a known algorithm of mapping N distinct strings to N distinct integers from 0 to N-1?

I feel like something like this already exists.

Comment: [Yeah, that's a thing.](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

These are known as [minimal perfect hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), and there are indeed known algorithms for finding them. I don't personally know the algorithms, but that's fine. Existing libraries can do it for you.

[CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) is good for finding minimal perfect hash functions for very large numbers of keys.

[gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/gperf.html) focuses on hash evaluation speed for small numbers of keys, where the perfect hash function is not required to be minimal (so there might be some empty space in the table).